# How to prove this equality about functions over indexed and intersecting sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $f:A\to B$ be a map of sets, and let $\left\{X_{i}\right\}_{i\in I}$ be an indexed collection of subsets of $A$. 
I need to prove that 

$f\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} X_{i}\right) \subset \bigcap_{i\in I} f(X_{i})$ 
 
I am under the impression that both $f\left(\bigcap_{i\in I} X_{i}\right)$ and $\bigcap_{i\in I} f(X_{i})$ can be evaluated as $\{f\left(x\right) \in B:\forall i\in I, x \in X_i\}$, which means that they are equal.
 Similarly, I am required to show that $f\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} X_{i}\right) = \bigcup_{i\in I} f(X_{i})$. My solution was to conclude that they both evaluate to $\{f\left(x\right) \in B:\exists i\in I \space s.t. \space x \in X_i\}$
 My understanding is clearly flawed but I don't understand how exactly.

Comment: Do you know how to do an element argument to prove a subset relation?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: About the second equality, it is the correct way to proceed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets need not be equal. Suppose that $A=B=\Bbb R$, $I=\{0,1\}$, $X_0$ is the set of negative real numbers, $X_1$ is the set of positive real numbers, and $f(x)=x^2$ for each $x\in\Bbb R$. Then $\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i=X_0\cap X_1=\varnothing$, so

$$f\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right]=f[\varnothing]=\varnothing\;,$$

but $f[X_0]=f[X_1]=X_1$, so

$$\bigcap_{i\in I}f[X_i]=X_1\ne\varnothing\;.$$

HINT: The most straightforward approach is simply to show that each member of the set $f\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right]$ belongs to the set $\bigcap_{i\in I}f[X_i]$. To do this, let $y$ be an arbitrary member of $f\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right]$. This means that $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$. Since $x\in\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$, we know that $x\in X_i$ for *every* $i\in I$, and therefore $y=f(x)\in f[X_i]$ for every $i\in I$. There’s just one small step left; can you finish it off?

Comment: $y=f(x)\in f[X_i]$ for every $i\in I$ for any arbitrary $y$ allows us to conclude that every element of $f\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right]$ is in $\bigcap_{i\in I}f\left[X_i\right]$, which is what we want. So this completes the proof. Does this also mean that the only time the two sets are equivalent is when $f(x)$ stays the same for all $x \in X_i$ for any $i \in I$?

Comment: @jessicajjensen: Your completion of the argument is fine. The question of when the two sets are equal is a bit more complicated than that: it happens when every $y\in\bigcap_{i\in I}f[X_i]$ is the image of some point in $\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$. The function $f$ can still do all sorts of weird things on $A\setminus\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$.

Comment: Just to clarify, does this mean that the two sets are equal when they have the same pre-image? That pre-image being $\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$.

Comment: @jessicajjensen: Yes, $$f\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i\right]=\bigcap_{i\in I}f[X_i]$$ if and only if $$\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i=f^{-1}\left[\bigcap_{i\in I}f[X_i]\right]\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a (classic, see Rudin Real and Complex Analysis) example of strict inclusion for the first case:

$ f:{1,2} \rightarrow {1} $ given by $ f(1)=1 \ \ \ f(2)=1$

Can you conclude yourself?